# Branch disappeared from local repo after commit

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I was on a local feature branch and did 'git add .' and then 'git commit -m [my message describing the commit]' then I tried to 'git push origin [branch_name]' which, even though there is no remote branch, I would have expected it to create one.

What I got was this error:
'error: src refspec does not match any 
git error: failed to push some refs to remote'

I then checked out a feature branch that was one commit behind the problematic branch, and checked but there was so problem, and it was up-to-date with remote. But then my problematic branch disappeared - now when I do a 'git branch' it does not appear! I also can't check it out!

What has happened here? I saved the new work in other files just to be sure I wouldn't lose anything, I just want to fix whatever has happend to my local repo so I can continue with the project without having this error again.

Thanks.

Comment: Strange, it appeared in a different git branch and then I could check it out as before....?